# unable to install sicktoolbox_wrapper

Tags: ros, laser, sensor, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

melab@melab1:~$ rosdep install sicktoolbox_wrapper

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource sicktoolbox_wrapper
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

this is what i get when i try to install, i am new to ROS, please help.

Also do i need matlab inorder the sicktoolbox to work ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172628/unable-to-install-sicktoolbox_wrapper/) by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sicktoolbox-wrapper
```

and your done.

Note: `rosdep install` installs the dependencies of a package, NOT the package itself.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-06-03**:
I used sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sicktoolbox-wrapper, the package got installed properly.
However running rosdep install sticktoolbox_wrapper still gives me an error. And if rosdep installs only the dependencies of the package then how do i download the package , by the apt-get ?

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-06-03**:
it worked, thanx a lot